# Making a nested list from objects in a list after passing through a function

Tags: python-3.x

This is on the topic of scientific computing and the fastest runtime is best.
Thus I am looking for a faster way to do it in one go, instead of passing the newly made list through another for loop.

I am trying to make a list of lists (a matrix) from a data set.
Original list is a 1 by N and passing each element through a mathematical expression I need to make a 3 by N matrix.

So far I have:

```
year = [1980,  1981, 1982, 1983]
list2 = []

def testing(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        list2.append(1)
        list2.append(year[i])
        list2.append(year[i]**2)

testing(year)
print(list2)
```

The output looks like this:

```
[1, 1980, 3920400, 1, 1981, 3924361, 1, 1982, 3928324, 1, 1983, 3932289]
```

Desired output:

```
[[1, 1980, 3920400], [1, 1981, 3924361], [1, 1982, 3928324], [1, 1983, 3932289]]
```

All help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using numpy?

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
def testing(a):
    return [[1, y, y**2] for y in a]

year = [1980,  1981, 1982, 1983]
list2 = testing(year)
print(list2)
```

Although depending on your use case, using tuples or numpy could be a better option.